# Can We Pass custom objects from native to JS in PhoneGap/Cordova?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-3, cordova-plugins

I am writing custom plugins for Phone Gap android app. Using  cordova's  PluginResult or CallbackContext, we can send string, byte array, JSON object or array to JavaScript success callback.

Is there any way we can pass some custom object like Person Or Employee or some complex object from Native(Java in my case) code to JS callback using cordova's  PluginResult or CallbackContext? or any other way to achieve this?

Any inputs or example code snippets are most welcome.

Comment: yes that's what plugins do, you can create your own, just google for a tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass only strings and objects, that can be serialized in strings, between native code and javascript parts.

Comment: Is this still valid? How would we go about exposing native objects inside a Cordova Plugin so that it can be used in JavaScript?

Comment: I think yes. "Exposing native objects" means cross-process wrappers between JS code and native code. And only serilizable objects can be passed through.